# Setup value provider for dropdown list field in Sitecore forms using IFieldValueProvider

Tags: sitecore-forms

I have a doubt regarding setting up a value provider for prefilling Sitecore forms, I can see there are examples for simple text input fields, and it's working, but when I try to set up a value provider for a dropdown list field it's not working. I tried below but no luck, can someone help me to figure out what am doing wrong here.

```
public class CountryListValueProvider : IFieldValueProvider
    {
        public FieldValueProviderContext ValueProviderContext { get; set; }
        public object GetValue(string parameters)
        {
            var countries = GetCountries();
            var countrList = new ListFieldItemCollection();
            foreach (var country in countries.data)
            {
                countrList.Add(new ListFieldItem
                {
                    Text = country.code,
                    Value = country.value
                });
            }
            switch (parameters)
            {
                case "countrList":
                    return countrList;
                default:
                    return string.Empty;
            }
        }
    }
```

Or do I need to try something else, like using IListDataSourceProvider or something (edited)

Comment: Are you able to debug this? And check if it is creating the perfect FieldItemCollection? @NijasHameed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main use of `Value Provider` is for prefilling `Sitecore forms`. So `Sitecore` has described how to implement that using the below article.

https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/93/sitecore-experience-manager/walkthrough--setting-up-a-value-provider-for-prefilling-forms.html

But in your case, if you want to pre-fill your value for a `dropdown list` then you only need to pass a list of strings like this. For example, if the value you want pre-fill is called "**prefillvalue**", then you code will be like this.

```
public object GetValue(string parameters)
{
   return new List<string> {"prefillvalue"};
}
```

Read this article for more details.

http://onelittlespark.bartverdonck.be/value-provider-on-list-components/

Comment: What if I wanted to pass the option containing text and value? can I use keyvalue pair?

Comment: @NijasHameed Follow this article if you want to achieve something that you want. (Check the title Create a List Data Source Provider) https://joaoneto.blog/create-a-dropdown-list-with-external-data-in-sitecore-forms/

Comment: Yes I tried this and got it worked, Thanks

Comment: @NijasHameed Please mark this as a verified answer if it resolved your issue. Thanks