# Set current date in Sitecore form datepicker

Tags: sitecore-forms, datetimepicker

Has anyone able to set the current date in Sitecore form 10.1 date picker?

Just like WFFM, we used the following script to set the current date.

```
@Html.RenderScriptBlock(
    @<script type="text/javascript">
         if (typeof window.WffmFieldsData === 'undefined') {
             window.WffmFieldsData = {}
         }

         window.WffmFieldsData["@Html.IdFor(x => Model.Value)"] =
         {
             'defaultDate': new Date('@Model.Value'),
             'dateFormat': '@ClientDateFormatConverter.ConvertToClientFormat(Model.DateFormat)',
             'minDate': new Date('@Model.StartDate.Year', '@(Model.StartDate.Month - 1)', '@Model.StartDate.Day'),
             'maxDate': new Date('@Model.EndDate.Year', '@(Model.EndDate.Month - 1)', '@Model.EndDate.Day'),
         };
     </script>
)
```

I want to do the same in Sitecore forms date picker.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set the default value in `Sitecore Form` controls for example a dropdown or a date picker then you need to implement a custom `Form Value Provider`.

You can follow this article to know how to implement a Value provide for prefilling form.

https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/91/sitecore-experience-manager/walkthrough--setting-up-a-value-provider-for-prefilling-forms.html

I have also given the answer to the same kind of scenario but that is for the drop-down list. Here is the link.

[Setup value provider for dropdown list field in Sitecore forms using IFieldValueProvider](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/31788/setup-value-provider-for-dropdown-list-field-in-sitecore-forms-using-ifieldvalue/31789#31789)

Hope this will help.